# jQuery changing the background colour of a div depending on its current colour

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Im new to jQuery and have been researching and playing with it as much as possible my issue is im running out of time i need to get this project done asap. Anyways my question...

I have a link when clicked it calls a jquery ajax function which is al working properly... upon success i want the code to change the background colour of a div but this depends on its current colour cause it can be switched back and forth between two colours...

anyways heres what ive been playing with...

```
highlightColor = "#d8fe00"; //Updated to not cause confusion...
whiteColor = "#ffffff"; //Updated to not cause confusion...

$("input[value*='" + cId + "']").closest("div[class*='link-black']").attr("background-color", function(iPos, color) {
if(color != highlightColor) { return highlightColor; }
else { return whiteColor; }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated thanks in advance!!

Comment: PS the attribute im using is a css attribute so not sure if there is some sort of other way to check that?

Comment: Can you show the HTML that the JS is working with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using [`.toggleClass`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass) instead:

**CSS:**

```
.highlight { background-color: 'yellow'; }
```

**JS:**

```
$("#selector").toggleClass("highlight");
```

Comment: I put that there only to show that my vars have values they have quotes and also have the actual color codes not yellow or white... I had a feeling that might cause confusion ill fix that now

Answer (score 1):

How about *not* styling with javascript and taking advantage of good ol' CSS?

**CSS**

```
.white { background-color: white; }
.white.highlight { background-color: yellow; }
.red { background-color: red; }
.red.highlight { background-color: pink; }
```

**JS**

```
 $("input[value*='" + cId + "']").closest("div[class*='link-black']").toggleClass('highlight');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.classOne { color: red; }
.classTwo { color: blue; }
.classThree { color: green; }

.classOne.highlighted { background-color: white; }
.classTwo.highlighted { background-color: black; }
.classThree.highlighted { background-color: purple; }
```

In the AJAX callback, all you have to do is add the "highlighted" class to your element.  You can let the CSS figure out which color the text is and which color the background should be.  The classes should obviously be more descriptive than `classOne` though.